# httpHandler Content-Length too short?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to download a PDF file via a `httpHandler`, but for some reason my `httpHandler` is returning an incorrect content-length size?

If i put this code into a normal aspx page, it works, so i can only guess that there is something different about `httpHandlers`?

Code is below (in c# and vb.net), i return an additional my-length header to see what the length of my `lData` array is

When i execute this in chrome, the content-length property is 842710, but my-length is 845942

Why are they different?  I have even tried to set content-length manually, but that does nothing...

Any help much appreicated

C#

```
byte[] lData = Document.GetData();

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();

' headers for response
context.Response.AddHeader("My-Length", lData.Length);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="""MyFile.PDF"""");

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(lData, 0, lData.Length);
context.Response.End();
```

VB.NET

```
Dim lData() As Byte = lDocument.GetData()

context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.ClearContent()
context.Response.ClearHeaders()

' headers for response
context.Response.AddHeader("My-Length", lData.Length)
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="""MyFile.PDF"""")

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(lData, 0, lData.Length)
context.Response.End()
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to inspect the response. Use the Hex window to look for additional data that was sent accidentally. Maybe garbage was appended.

Comment: Will look at this... the weord thing it the larger file works and the smaller file downloaded by the handler is corrup

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a Response.Flush before Response.End.  Streams can be quirky sometimes.

```
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(lData, 0, lData.Length);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```